# node proxy server, bottle neck?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, proxy

We have 2 servers:

1. File API
2. Core API

File API on different server and the core API on different. We want to access both over same domain and port, we are using `nodeJS` as back-end platform.

So we came up with a solution of proxy server, *(see the below illustration)*:

[image]

**Now the question is**, will `http-node-proxy` create bottle neck on the proxy server or it will be a good architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `nginx` as a reverse proxy server, and the Node.js apps as upstreams.

There are a lot of articles about this, I think that for example

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

is a good start.

Comment: Won't it give all the load of all servers on a single proxy server? If it works as a tunnel between client and my server, so all the data will go through the proxy server.

Comment: Yes, and? The same would apply to node-proxy... Only that nginx is proven to work in production... And, that's exactly what your diagram suggests. So I don't really understand your concerns...